# How to add an image to a turtle object in python?

Tags: python

```
# register shape
turt = turtle.Turtle()
turt.register_shape('player.png')
# player
p = turtle.Turtle()
p.speed(0)

p.color('magenta')

p.shape('player.png')
p.shapesize(2)
p.setheading(0)
p.penup()

p.setposition(-700, 0)
hp = 3
```

then i get this error: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'register_shape'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`register_shape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.register_shape) is not a method on `Turtle` objects, it's a global function.

So, instead of this:

```
turt.register_shape('player.png')
```

… do this:

```
turtle.register_shape('player.png')
```

---

Also, notice that you don't have any use for that `turt` turtle. Your app only wants to display a single turtle, `p`, so don't create any others.

---

Finally, even after you fix this:

At least according to the docs, only GIF images are supported, but you're trying to use a PNG image. The docs may be wrong about that, but there's a good chance they're right, and this is going to fail.

If so, the only way to fix it is to use some other program (it could be one you write yourself in 4 lines of Pillow code, or it could be something like MSPaint or Preview, or a command-line tool like ImageMagick convert) to make a GIF image out of your PNG image.

Comment: actually their are more turtles its just that I'm trying to add the picture to that turtle so i only sent that much code. If that is a problem please tell how I can fix it